# Freeglut program compiles but when run, shows the error: libglut.so.3: cannot open shared object file

Tags: opengl, shared-libraries, freeglut

This is my program:

```
#include </usr/local/include/GL/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(320,320);
    glutCreateWindow("Lighthouse3D- GLUT Tutorial");
}
```

Compiled with:

> g++ -lglut -L/usr/local/lib/ -o start
>   start.cpp;./start

Error shown:

> ./start: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libglut.so.3: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

The file is present.

> bashprompt> locate libglut.so.3
>   /usr/local/lib/libglut.so.3
>   /usr/local/lib/libglut.so.3.9.0

Had also tried:

> LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/local/lib/"
>   g++ -lglut -LLIBDIR -o start start.cpp;./start
>   with no luck.

These were the messages shown while installing (if this helps):

> root@Nav:/home/Nav/freeglut-2.6.0#
>   make install   Making install in src
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   `/home/Nav/freeglut-2.6.0/src'
>
>   make[2]: Entering directory`
>   /home/Nav/freeglut-2.6.0/src'   test
>   -z "/usr/local/lib" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib"    /bin/sh ../libtool
>   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c  'libglut.la'
>   '/usr/local/lib/libglut.la'
>   /usr/bin/install -c
>   .libs/libglut.so.3.9.0
>   /usr/local/lib/libglut.so.3.9.0 (cd
>   /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f
>   libglut.so.3.9.0 libglut.so.3 || { rm
>   -f libglut.so.3 && ln -s libglut.so.3.9.0 libglut.so.3; }; })
>   (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f
>   libglut.so.3.9.0 libglut.so || { rm -f
>   libglut.so && ln -s libglut.so.3.9.0
>   libglut.so; }; })   /usr/bin/install
>   -c .libs/libglut.lai /usr/local/lib/libglut.la
>   /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libglut.a
>   /usr/local/lib/libglut.a   chmod 644
>   /usr/local/lib/libglut.a   ranlib
>   /usr/local/lib/libglut.a
>   PATH="$PATH:/sbin" ldconfig -n
>   /usr/local/lib
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------   Libraries have been installed in:
>   /usr/local/lib      If you ever happen
>   to want to link against installed
>   libraries   in a given directory,
>   LIBDIR, you must either use libtool,
>   and   specify the full pathname of the
>   library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'   flag
>   during linking and do at least one of
>   the following:
>
>      - add LIBDIR to the`LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
>        during execution
>      - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
>        during linking
>
>      - use the`-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
>      - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
>   See any operating system documentation
>   about shared libraries for   more
>   information, such as the ld(1) and
>   ld.so(8) manual pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `LD_RUN_PATH` attempt was very close, but it should be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
./start
```

This tip from the installer is also handy:

> have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

If you did that, you wouldn't need to do the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` thing.

Comment: You have to call `glutMainLoop()` after `glutCreateWindow()`, or the program will just exit before the window even appears.